# How I can show data from API in edit text if user authorized in app kotlin?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, authorization, okhttp

I have one query inside okHttp3 network api calls. I have used Header to authorization. I'm able to get data inside onResponse() and further storing it inside sqliteDatabase. Let me correct in my approach. 
my code snippet is below.

**My Login.kt:**

```
class Login : AppCompatActivity() {
    fun requestAuth(url: String) {
        var param = FormBody.Builder()
            .add("login", login.text.toString())
            .add("password", password.text.toString())
            .build()
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).post(param).build()
        val client = OkHttpClient()
            .newBuilder()
            .build()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback{
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                startActivity(Intent(this@Login, NavigationMenu::class.java)
                    .putExtra("session_token", response
                        .header("session_token")
                        .toString()))    
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

            bin.setOnClickListener {

                if (login.text.toString() != "" && password.text.toString() != "") {
//                    requestAuth("https://example.com/api/1.0/user/auth")
                    val i = Intent(this, NavigationMenu::class.java)
                    startActivity(i)
                } else toast("Wrong password")
            }
```

**My Activity.kt** (empty fields for registration and must be fill for authorized user)

```
class AboutSale : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_sale)

        val ext = intent.getIntExtra("singup",1)
        if (ext == 1) {
            back.setOnClickListener {
                finish()
            }
            next.setOnClickListener {

                if (namesale.text.toString() == "") toast("Field is empty")
                else if (engsale.text.toString() == "") toast("Sale description is empty")
                else if (sizesale.text.toString() == "") toast("Field is empty")
                else if (providersale.text.toString() == "") toast("Field is empty")

                else {
                    val i = Intent(this, AboutCompany::class.java)
                        .putExtra("singup", 1)
                        .putExtra("login", intent.extras?.getString("login"))
                        .putExtra("password", intent.extras?.getString("password"))
                        .putExtra("namesale", namesale.text.toString())
                        .putExtra("engsale", engsale.text.toString())
                        .putExtra("sizesale", sizesale.text.toString())
                        .putExtra("providersale", providersale.text.toString())
                        .putExtra("category", intent.extras?.getString("category"))
                        .putExtra("category2", intent.extras?.getString("category2"))
                        .putExtra("category3", intent.extras?.getString("category3"))
                        .putExtra("category4", intent.extras?.getString("category4"))
                        .putExtra("tag", intent.extras?.getString("tag"))
                        .putExtra("tag2", intent.extras?.getString("tag2"))
                    startActivity(i)
                }
            }
        } else {
            back.setOnClickListener {
                finish()
            }
            next.setOnClickListener {
                startActivity(Intent(this, NavigationMenu::class.java))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you have any structure for okHttp3 then kindly suggest. any suggestions/corrections are appreciable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all you need to structure your code little bit. hope you can found okhttp call on google, still you can refer this, https://www.journaldev.com/13629/okhttp-android-example-tutorial .

Comment: additionally in side onResponse() , log your response first and then start your NavigationMenu activity. you can pass values using intent in onReceive() method of okHttp and inside NavigationMenu activity get that values form intent and display in edit text

Comment: @Radhey I tried it but it's for java and i try to make `txtString.setText(json.getJSONObject("data").getString("first_name")` for me like `editText.text = json.getJSONObject("data").getString("text")` but got "Found: Editable! Required: String`. Do you have some idea where I mistake?
Log my response it is mean use logcat or debug to see my response or put my response in some variable to store it?

Comment: you are not paring json correctly. just go step by step . log each value in string what ever you want to fillup inside edit text first.